# AndroidStudio: Howto to open SQLite File in SQLScout Plugin

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Installed SQLScout Plugin -> ok.
I have an file.db, which is a sqlite database . Can be opened in another SQLite Manager Tool.

How can I assign that file to be viewed with the plugin ?

I doubleclicked on the file , popup coms up to assign any view? like HTML, SQL ..., but no SQLScout available to choose.

How can I open my sqlite db in AndroidStudio ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you install the SQLScout plugin in android studio then you need to restart studio after that you can see the **SQLite Explorer** option in **Tool Window.**

**View-> Tool Window->SQLite Explorer**

[image]

**Open SQLite Explorer Window**

[image]

Now, You can open your SQLite Database file via two ways.

**1. First Way**

- Open Device Explorer Window and navigate to **data->data->xxx.xxx.com(app package name)->databases**.
- Now you can see your application database file with **.db** extension and save database file into local machine.
- Now open SQLite explorer window
- Expand **+** button and click on **Local SQLite Database** then open new window

[image]

- Enter database name and database file path which you saved earlier.

[image]

- Now, you can see the tables.

[image]

**2. Second Way**

Please follow the below links.

http://www.idescout.com/features/#sqlite_explorer

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8322-sqlscout-sqlite-support-

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: This is not visible for me

Answer (score -1):

if u installed the correct version of SqlScout you will see a label at the right corner of the android studios labeled Sq-lite Explorer then click on the + then check for your database name is correct then execute Ur query's after that.